# marginal likelihood after linear discriminant analysis projection

Tags: bayesian, references, likelihood, variational-bayes

Suppose I have a set of observation from GMM. I want to observe the change of marginal likelihood (model evidence) after LDA projection.

I'm guessing that it would get bigger. Is there any known result about this?

Comment: What is GMM? Can you spell it out?

Comment: I mean gaussian mixture model.

Comment: Please can you addis as an exit to theoriginalpost?